# Average of multiple queries

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, average, divide

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

I'm trying to get the Average profit from the prior 3 months, then get the profit from last month, and then I want to perform a calculation to compare last month's profit to the prior 3 month average.

So example :

SUM of Profit for current month -2 
SUM of Profit for current month -3 
SUM of Profit for current month -4

Average of (SUM of Profit for current month -2 + SUM of Profit for current month -3 + SUM of Profit for current month -4)  = prior 3 Month Average

prior 3 month average / SUM of profit for last month = difference

The code I have so far is :

```
select SUM(profit)as 'threemonthavg'
from invoices
where DATEPART(MM, SHIPPED_DATE) = DATEPART(MM, Dateadd(MM, -2, getdate()))
and DATEPART(YYYY, shipped_date) = DATEPART(YYYY, Dateadd(MM, -2, getdate()))
union
select SUM(profit)
from invoices
where DATEPART(MM, SHIPPED_DATE) = DATEPART(MM, Dateadd(MM, -3, getdate()))
and DATEPART(YYYY, shipped_date) = DATEPART(YYYY, Dateadd(MM, -3, getdate()))
union
select SUM(profit)
from invoices
where DATEPART(MM, SHIPPED_DATE) = DATEPART(MM, Dateadd(MM, -4, getdate()))
and DATEPART(YYYY, shipped_date) = DATEPART(YYYY, Dateadd(MM, -4, getdate()))
```

This gives me the sum of each month's profit in 3 cells. Perfect. Now I'd like to Average those numbers so I place it in a subquery:

```
select AVG([threemonthavg])
from
(
select SUM(profit) as 'threemonthavg'
from invoices
where DATEPART(MM, SHIPPED_DATE) = DATEPART(MM, Dateadd(MM, -2, getdate()))
and DATEPART(YYYY, shipped_date) = DATEPART(YYYY, Dateadd(MM, -2, getdate()))
union
select SUM(profit)
from invoices
where DATEPART(MM, SHIPPED_DATE) = DATEPART(MM, Dateadd(MM, -3, getdate()))
and DATEPART(YYYY, shipped_date) = DATEPART(YYYY, Dateadd(MM, -3, getdate()))
union
select SUM(profit)
from invoices
where DATEPART(MM, SHIPPED_DATE) = DATEPART(MM, Dateadd(MM, -4, getdate()))
and DATEPART(YYYY, shipped_date) = DATEPART(YYYY, Dateadd(MM, -4, getdate()))
)x
```

...so now I have my average. Now I need last months profit which is pretty easy to get, but how do I merge the above query with the query for last month's profit in order to perform a division calculation? I've tried numerous joins but I can't get the syntax correct. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable for each query to store to the query result then perform your division. Here few example of declaring variables...........

DECLARE @iVariable INT, @vVariable VARCHAR(100), @dDateTime DATETIME

SET @iVariable = 1

SET @vVariable = 'myvar'

SET @dDateTime = GETDATE()

SELECT @iVariable iVar, @vVariable vVar, @dDateTime dDT

GO